# Table center not working

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am new to latex. I have tried to make the following table center. I have tried **\centering** and **\begin{center}** both approach. However, it is not moving a bit. How to make this table center. Thank you.

```
\begin{table}
      \caption{Abstract configuration of the device used in scraping}
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \hline\hline  
    Name & : & Inspur NF5170M4 1U Server                                        \\
    Processor & : & Intel®Xeon®E5-2600V3 or V4\\ Processors
    Chipset & : & Intel ®C610 server chipset\\
    Memory & : & 32GB \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
      \end{minipage}
      \label{table1}
    \end{table}
```

The following part is the head part. In case you need.

```
\documentclass{nle}
\makeatletter
\let\O@argtabularcr\@argtabularcr
\def\O@xtabularcr{\@ifnextchar[\O@argtabularcr{\ifnum 0=`{\fi}\cr}}
\let\O@tabacol\@tabacol
\let\O@tabclassiv\@tabclassiv
\let\O@tabclassz\@tabclassz
\let\O@tabarray\@tabarray
\def\author@tabular{\authorsize\def\@halignto{}\@authortable}
\let\endauthor@tabular=\endtabular
\def\author@tabcrone{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\O@xtabularcr\affilsize\itshape
 \let\\=\author@tabcrtwo\ignorespaces}
\def\author@tabcrtwo{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\O@xtabularcr[-3\p@]\affilsize\itshape
 \let\\=\author@tabcrtwo\ignorespaces}
\def\@authortable{\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\O@tabacol
 \let\@classz\O@tabclassz \let\@classiv\O@tabclassiv
 \let\\=\author@tabcrone \ignorespaces \O@tabarray}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

for above result i remove `minipage` environment and add `\centering` after `\begin{table}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
      \caption{Abstract configuration of the device used in scraping}
      \label{table1}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \hline\hline
Name & : & Inspur NF5170M4 1U Server                                        \\
Processor & : & Intel®Xeon®E5-2600V3 or V4\\ Processors
Chipset & : & Intel ®C610 server chipset\\
Memory & : & 32GB \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thank you.